# Inline css is not working in ck editor full html

Tags: wysiwyg

I have installed updated version of the [CKEditor - WYSIWYG HTML editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module with CK editor library.

Every time I put `inline css` in my **HTML full editor**, it vanished.

I have searched the web for it, but not found proper solution.

Anybody any suggestions about this?

Comment: You probably need to allow the style to be set on divs, https://www.drupal.org/node/454408#comment-8501471

Comment: This din solve my problem..Please suggest me other solution

Comment: htmLawed module allows you to set allowed attributes afaik. https://www.drupal.org/project/htmlawed

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example where you can add inline class to P tag. Similarly you can do this with other tags. [Refer CKEditor documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules-section-string-format)

In the "**Advanced Content Filter**" section of CKEditor profile add this:

```
P [*]
```

[image]

In the "**Advanced options**" section of CKEditor profile add this:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

[image]

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the Advanced content filter settings of you profile: You can add an exception or disable it.